# Cannot query 'AutomatedAction'?

Tags: soql, standard-objects

According to the Object Reference, [`AutomatedAction`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_automatedaction.htm) is a Standard Object available in API 57.0 and later.  However, I have tried querying it from Developer Console, from Apex, and via SOAP API in a couple of orgs, and I get the error:

> Object type 'AutomatedAction' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name.

Is there some special permission needed?  I have the standard Sysadmin profile in orgs where I have tested this.

(**NOTE:**  What am I trying to accomplish?  I'm down a rabbit hole trying to see if there is a way to query the scheduled (future) publication time of a Knowledge Article, which doesn't appear to be possible, but along the way I ran into this object, and now I want to understand why it isn't available.)

Comment: Do you have [Sales Engagement](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.hvs_setup_enable.htm&type=5) (FKA High Velocity Sales) enabled in your org? This object should be available for use upon enabling it